# Java web application is slow

Tags: java, web, netbeans-7, performance

I am new to java web application development. I just wrote the first hello world application using the netbeans 7.3 IDE. When the application is launched, it keeps loading for more than 30minutes. I don't think that this is usual. Is there a way around this problem? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do your log files show anything?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your home servlet?

Comment: Something is completely wrong. Try to re-install your environment, e.g. Netbeans. A typical Hello-World web app should start in less then 3 seconds.

Comment: Sounds more like the IDE not fully understanding the server being used. I had the same issue a long time ago when trying to use JBoss 7 in Netbeans; the IDE simply didn't understand when the server was finished booting because the server manager had no support for the server yet.

Comment: Thanks alot. Re-installing the environment got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your app is a simple Hello World (without external dependencies) potential performance issues can be caused by:

- Network Connection. 30 s sounds like a timeout. Some  3rd party libs used in web apps refer by default to Internet URIs resources like XML schemas for validation.
- JVM swapping due not enough free memory. This can impact your JVM  performance.
- JVM running out of Permanent Space. If your JVM is Hot Spot look for error messages in the log. In this case just increase the -XX:MaxPermSize java argument (256m is a good starting point).

To help diagnosis:
 - Capture a sequence of Thead Dumps ( kill -3 PID for Linux/UNIX or Ctrl+Brk in Windows) 3 or 5  every 5 secs) to see what hangs the JVM ( network access to schemas, file system access, ...). Some tools like Samurai can help you to detect threads stuck in the same line of code .
 - Check your system free memory
 - Check your logs for memory errors (stdout,stderr)